# What's the physical origin of bound states in the continuum (BICs)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

[image: Fig.1 Bound states in the continuum(BIC)]

From my point of view, BICs are modes built by destructive interference. But I'm confused about the orgin of BIC, I have two questions:

1. The differences between BIC modes and defect modes.

It has been reported that some previous research mistaked defect modes with BICs. However, still I cannot tell the differences between BIC modes and defect modes, especially when we focus on quasi-BIC. Since we can see a DBR cavity as a structure supporting BIC, I think BIC is just a different way to view the problem instead of something new.

I know that there are some symmetry protected BICs without any defects or special designs(like BIC vortex beam generator), but I'm confused about the relationship between the topological nature and basic characteristics(symmetry protected or parametric).

[image: Fig.2 This structure forms a waveguide(continuum) near defect cavity]

2. How can BICs survive in individual structures.
   When it comes to individual structures without any particular design, it's so strange that they can support BICs. Are they real BICs?

Changing the parameters of the structures to reach high Q modes, I think, is very similar to normal optimization. Is there something special lies inside when we use BIC to view it?

[image: Individual nanopost can support BICs]

References
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBOXZ.png)Hsu C W, et al. Nat. Rev. Mater., 2016
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjiaU.png)Bogdanov A A, et al. Adv. Photonics, 2019
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8XH5.png)Koshelev K, et al. Science, 2020

Comment: Consider to write out the acronyms.

Comment: I wonder if another way to look at it is non-radiating configurations. In electrodynamics you can have localized configurations of oscillating currents that emmit no light. Are these bound states in continuum? I tend to think about them as of functions in the null-space of Maxwells equations

Comment: Do you refer to BIC? Sorry, I should have written it down. BIC is Bound state In the Continuum. @Jakob

Comment: Your point of view is illuminating! Could you please provide more information about "functions in the null-space of Maxwells equations"? I'm hearing that term for the first time. @Cryo

Comment: @DavidZhong, Gbur's thesis has a nice intro into it https://pages.charlotte.edu/greg-gbur/wp-content/uploads/sites/158/2012/11/thesis.pdf. More recent viewpoint, more from the anapole/toroidal dipole side of things is in https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/361908/1/Savinov.pdf (see Chapter 4). Also there is http://www.nanophotonics.org.uk/niz/publications/Savinov-2019-OA.pdf

Comment: I also really like [Nonpropagating string excitations – finite length and damped strings](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165212598900543). [Devaney's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Foundations-Tomography-Wavefield-Inversion/dp/052111974X) has a lot on this topic too (e.g. sec 2.7).

You have Devaney, Wolf, Gbur - the school of nonradiating configurations; 
Zeldovich, Dubovik, Zheludev - anapoles/toroidal dipoles 

and you also have more recent work on BIC, which goes back to Wigner, but its electrodynamics branch is more recent

Comment: the thing to remember here is that fields in, e.g., dielectrics,l are basically displacement currents. in metals - conduction currents. This links BIC, whis mostly about fields, to non-radiating configurations, which is mostly about currents. Anapoles in metamaterials is a good example of this

Comment: Wow, @Cryo, thank you so much! This is a lot to digest! There is a small question, do you mean BIC is mainly about fields while anapole is about currents?

Comment: @DavidZhong I have made a proper reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Intro

As far as I can see from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state_in_the_continuum
https://doi.org/10.1126/science.aaz3985

and from my previous brief experience, BIC in photonics refers to having an electromagnetic excitation that looks like it 'could' propagate away but don't. What it looks like normally is that there is some structure and some specific kind of excitation that stays pinned to the spot, even though you can have other electromagnetic waves propagating in the same space.

### Problem statement

Is this strange to have electromagnetic excitation being fixed to a single place? I don't think so. Imagine having an excitation sitting inside a finite-sized perfect electric conductor sphere. It will sit there it will not go anywhere etc. Clearly this is not too helpful, more generally we can ask: *Under which conditions can you localize electromagnetic excitation in a space that supports propagating waves?*

### Dielectrics/Metals/Domains -> Currents

Before continuing it is helpful to get away from considering bits of dielectric, defects in photonic crystals etc. Instead we will focus on homogeneous space (could be free space, could be photonic crystal) and currents in that space. The time-harmonic wave equation for electric field ($\mathbf{E}$) in this case is:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}-\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\epsilon\left(\mathbf{r}\right)\mathbf{E}\right)&=-i\omega \mu_0\mathbf{J} \\
\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}-\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}\right)&=-i\omega\mu_0\left( \mathbf{J}+\frac{-\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\cdot\left(\epsilon_0-\epsilon\left(\mathbf{r}\right)\right)\cdot\mathbf{E}}{-i\omega\mu_0}\right)
\end{align}
$$

What I have done there is to convert the spatially dependent part of the complex dielectric constant ($\epsilon\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$) into current density ($\mathbf{J}$). What this shows is that photonic BIC problems, which often rely on some non-trivially structured materials and defects, e.g. dielectric particles, can be considered as problems of electrodynamics in homogeneous space (permittivity $\epsilon_0$, permeability $\mu_0$, speed of light $c^2=1/\epsilon_0\mu_0$) with some oscillating current density.

### Non-radiating configurations

Now we can restate the problem as follows:

*Can you have a localized oscillating distribution of current density in homogeneous space (that supports wave propagation), which emits no radiation?*

The answer is yes you can: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.1044 (Devaney, Wolf, PRD 8, 1044 (1973))

In particular, a current density of the form:

$$
\mathbf{J}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{f}+\alpha\mathbf{f}
$$

Where $\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$ is some localized time-harmonic vector field, and $\alpha$ is a suitable constant (depends on how you write your Maxwell's equations), will always emit no light.

### Anapoles

Anapoles are point-like excitations (https://doi.org/10.1038/s42005-019-0167-z, V. Savinov et al. Comm Phys, 2:69 (2019) ) with time-harmonic current density:

$$
\mathbf{J}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{N}\delta\left(\mathbf{r}\right)+\alpha\mathbf{N}\delta\left(\mathbf{r}\right)
$$

Where $\mathbf{N}$ is a vector. It should be clear that Devaney-Wolf non-radiating configurations can be assembled from anapoles.

Interestingly anapoles, and the linked toroidal dipoles occur naturally in nuclear physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_moment

### Conclusion

What is the origin of bound states? The physical origin is that electromagnetic (dyadic) Green function ($\mathbf{G}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\right)$) has non-empty null-space - such are Maxwell's equations. Hence if electric field is given by:

$$
\mathbf{E}\left(r\right)=\int_V d^3r' \mathbf{G}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\right).\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r'}\right)
$$

It is possible to have vanishing electric field outside $V$ even with non-vanishing oscillating current density $\mathbf{J}$.

Light is emitted by oscillating currents and charges, but not all oscillating currents and charges have to emit light.

Comment: Does your last sentence miss an "all" or "every"  ? Like "..., but not all oscillating currents and charges have to emit light."

Comment: yep, thanks ...............

Comment: Wow, terrific! Considering oscillating current is a new perspective for me! I think the reference information you provided earlier will be very helpful for me to understand.

Comment: Your "perfect electric conductor sphere" get us to the point, pure non-radiating sources is probably not helpfu. I think our aim is to "extract" the electromagnetic waves (as we wish) from these sources while maintaining part of their non-radiating advantages (like high Quality factor). 

For example, to my knowledge, **practical anapoles** cancel its far-field radiation and localize the energy to the near field (can be detected with near-field microscopy), enhancing near-field light-matter interation, which is useful in some cases.

Comment: Therefore, when we focus on the pratical use, I wonder _how different will the "non-radiating method" be from our previous research?_ For optical anapole, it was first discovered in a nanodisk in 2015. However, nanodisk is not something new at that time, I guess the manipulation on this simple structure may be done previously without getting related to the anapole theory. When it comes to BIC, it gets more strange. Photonic crystal defects or nanoparticles, as you mentioned, are used to support BIC. However, these structures, especially nanoparticles, undergo no special treatment.

Comment: Although there are many theories that can well describe pure anapole and ideal BIC, I suspect if there is essentially new physics underlying when we discuss about the propagating-wave-excited pratical anapoles and quasi-BICs (leaky modes).

Comment: @Cryo, Hi, after some paper search, I think **the physical orgin is intereference**, both for BICs and anapoles. For BICs, there are some articles mention this point, like [link](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6633/abefb9)(the title of the article) and [link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/adom.202001469)(Figure 1b). The method you provide is reasonable, **maybe the oscilation of current is to form intereference**. Wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state_in_the_continuum) also uses "in phase" and "bragg mirror" to show BICs' intereference nature.

Comment: @DavidZhong, I see no problem in describing interference as the origin. I would only note that interference is not a well-defined concept. **You** choose to break electromagnetic field into different parts, and then add it together to assess whether or not the result is zero. It works well due to linearity of Maxwell's equations, and it often helps to break complicated problems into simple ones. But fundamentally interference requires you to define what interferes with what. I would say that origin is Maxwell's equations. They support such BIC and non-radiating solutions

Comment: @Cryo Yeah, I totally agree with you. Thank you very much!